# How can you iterate through ng-models within an ng-repeat in an angular controller?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I am pretty new to web dev and trying out angular so there may be many mistakes..
Basically I have a ng-repeat within an ng-repeat and I need to set a model variable within the child repeat onclick of a checkbox in parent repeat. 
I don't know how to access the models in the child from the parent. I have tried by giving an [$index] but it does not work.

Here is my HTML. I have a parent checkbox which should change the clicked boolean variable of child checkboxes onclick.

```
<li ng-repeat="set in wordlistSets" ng-controller="setController">

<div class="parentSelector">
<span class="selectorLeft">
    <p> blah </p>
</span>

<span class="selectorRight">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sets" ng-click="selectAll()">
</span>
</div>

<div  ng-repeat="wordlist in set.content"  ng-click="checked[parent.$index][$index] = !checked[parent.$index][$index]">
<span class="selectorLeft">
    <p>more blah</p><br>
    <p>extra blah</p>
</span>

<span class="selectorRight">
    <input type="checkbox" name="wordLists" ng-click="checked[parent.$index][$index] = !checked[parent.$index][$index]" ng-model="checked[parent.$index][$index]">

</span>
</div>
```

The "SelectAll()" function should iterate through wordlists and toggle the checked variable accordingly. I cant use angulars ng-checked because I need it to toggle and not have the same state as the parent checkbox allways since it can also be set by clciking on the div itself.

Here is the controller.

```
myApp.controller("setController", function MyController($scope) {
$scope.parentChecked = false;

$scope.selectAll = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.set.content; i++) {
        if ($scope.parentChecked) {
            $scope.checked[$scope.index][i] = true;
        } else {
            $scope.checked[$scope.index][i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a picture for reference. Clicking on either the pink selector or the black parent-selector should tick the checkbox.
[Picture of page setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYr07.png)

Thanks in advance for any help! :D

Comment: For each individual checkbox use `ng-change` to call controller function to iterate  `$scope.checked` to see if parent needs to be checked or not. A small sample of data would help in question so this can be tested by others. Even better is if you can copy this to [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) demo with a little bit of data. Don't need any css really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you need the check-boxes of the children to all work independently, correct?  In that case, your best bet is to keep a checkedWordlists array.

```
$scope.checkedWordlists = [];

$scope.toggleWordlist = function(wordlist) {
   var idx = $scope.checkedWordlists.indexOf(wordlist);
   if (idx>-1) {
      $scope.checkedWordlists.splice(idx);
   } else {
      $scope.checkedWordlists.push(wordlist);
   }
}
```

In your view,

```
<div  ng-repeat="wordlist in set.content"  ng-click="toggleWordlist(wordlist)">
<span class="selectorLeft">
    <p>more blah</p><br>
    <p>extra blah</p>
</span>

<span class="selectorRight">
    <input type="checkbox" name="wordLists" 
           ng-click="toggleWordlist(wordlist)" 
           ng-checked="checkedWordlists.indexOf(wordlist)>-1">
</span>
```

Lastly, to handle the parent checkbox:

```
$scope.toggleAll = function(wordlists) {
    var allToggled = $scope.allToggled()
    wordlists.forEach(function(wordlist) {
       if (allToggled == ($scope.checkedWordlists.indexOf(wordlist)>-1) {
           $scope.toggleWordlist(wordList);
       }
    })  
}
$scope.allToggled = function(wordlists) {
    var untoggledExist = wordlists.any(fucntion(wordlist) {
        return $scope.checkedWordlists.indexOf(wordlist) = -1
    });
    return !untoggledExist;
}
```

And the html:

```
<span class="selectorRight">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sets" 
              ng-click="toggleAll(set.content)"
              ng-checked="allToggled(set.content)">
</span>
```

This should do most of it.  I haven't tested this, but if you want to include a dataset above, we can create a fiddle to make sure it works.

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was after! I didn't know how to use the forEach loop in this case or add wordlists to the array. Though I cant figure out what wordlists.any is and neither can javasript. Anyway, I've got it to work with slightly different code :)

Comment: Sorry, that should be 'wordlists.some()'.  I always think of it as 'any' and then need to change the code after I get and error :-).  I'm glad it helped.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the above comment I got it to work perfectly after playing around with it for a bit. Ill post my solution here:

Some things to note. array.splice was not working in the way above user posted, it should take two variables as such:  array.splice(index, numOfThingToRemove); If given just an index of item to remove, it will remove that item and all items after it in the array.

Here is controller code:

```
$scope.parentChecked = false;
$scope.checkedWordlists = [];

$scope.selectAll = function(wordlists) {m
    //toggle parent
    if ($scope.parentChecked == false) {
        $scope.parentChecked = true;
    } else {
        $scope.parentChecked = false;
    }

    wordlists.forEach(function(wordlist) {
        $scope.setChild(wordlist, $scope.parentChecked);
    });
};

$scope.toggleCheckbox = function(wordlist) {
    var index = $scope.checkedWordlists.indexOf(wordlist);

    if (index > -1) {//is in array
        $scope.checkedWordlists.splice(index, 1);//remove from array
    } else {
        $scope.checkedWordlists.push(wordlist);//add to array
    }
};

$scope.setChild = function(wordlist, parentChecked) {
    var index = $scope.checkedWordlists.indexOf(wordlist);

    if (parentChecked && index <= -1) {//is not in array
        $scope.checkedWordlists.push(wordlist);//add to array
    } else if (!parentChecked && index > -1) {//is in array
        $scope.checkedWordlists.splice(index, 1);//remove from array
    }
};
```

and html:

```
<li ng-repeat="set in wordlistSets" ng-controller="setController">

<div class="parentSelector">
<span class="selectorLeft">
    <p> blah </p>
</span>

<span class="selectorRight">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sets" ng-click="selectAll(set.content)" ng-checked="parentChecked">
</span>
</div>

<div  ng-repeat="wordlist in set.content"  ng-click="toggleCheckbox(wordlist)">
<span class="selectorLeft">
    <p>more blah</p><br>
    <p>extra blah</p>
</span>

<span class="selectorRight">
    <input type="checkbox" name="wordLists"  ng-checked="checkedWordlists.indexOf(wordlist)> -1">

</span>
</div>
```

Thank you all so much for your help! :3

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the syntax error in array.splice and array.some (instead of .any).  Glad you got it working.